# Map the uv values as the color of a material

Tags: uv, node-editor, color

Using the material node compositor, I need to translate the x and y of the uvs of a mesh (assuming they are ranged from 0 to 1), to the red and green color value of a material.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, **just plugging the "UV" outlet of the "Texture Coordinate" node into the "Color" property of your shader should work**. This is because, by chance, your choice of colors (red, green) matches the R, G, B order.

---

**A more elegant and controllable way is in the node setup below**. The three nodes in the middle are MixRGB nodes, using the "Mix" and "Add" blend modes. Note: the *Fac:* value for "Add" must be 1.0.

You may want to swap red ↔ black and green ↔ black, as currently higher X/Y values give lower red/green intensities.

[image: suggested setup and result]